# Javascript "Object Required" Error

Tags: javascript

I'm working at an organization that only uses IE 8 (Windows 7). Every user gets a policy that includes a predefined set of settings. I have a problem with a javascript code only occurring on 2 machines (these two machines are from the same department). 
The line of code is:

```
if (mgr[k] == SystemUser().substr(1, SystemUser.length))
```

The error I get is "Object Required". I've also written a code to display a message of each value and found that the error is regarding the function SystemUser().

I need an idea to what might cause this error to show on those 2 machines. Is there a definition in the internet options that will block this function? Do I need to install something for it to be supported?

I'm inserting the SystemUser() code

```
function SystemUser(){
   WShShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
   return WshShell.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show us a little more of your code?   I can't find any reference to SystemUser being part of JavaScript out of the box, so it's likely it's part of another library.

Comment: Can you provide the SystemUser() code?

Comment: I've added the SystemUser() function, thank you for the comment.

Comment: You say the problem oocures only on two machines. And we can see `ActiveXObject` involved with some object being required. The error probably oocures in line `return WshShell.UserName;` because `WshShell` is undefined. Maybe you need to install a certain IE plugin to those two machines? Can you please confirm this and add the line where the error occures to your question? -- Btw: consider updating your IE - IE 8 is more than 5 years old. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I realized that the problem was in accessing the function SystemUser(). The function was written in an external js file. Both users, using these machines, did not have permissions to read the js file.

Granting them read permission to the external script solved the problem.